# Ruby .join method returning length of original array instead of concatenated string

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I am tyring to repeat a word an optional number of times. However when I run my program it does not seem to get past the `input[1].times do line`.

**CODE:**

```
def repeat(*input)
    sentence = []
    if input.length == 1
        "#{input[0]} #{input[0]}"
    else
        input[1].times do
            sentence.push(input[0])
            sentence.join(" ")
        end
    end
end

puts repeat("Hey!")

puts repeat("Hey", 3)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hey! Hey!
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the sentence, and you want to join the sentence outside of the times loop.

```
def repeat(*input)
    sentence = []
    if input.length == 1
        "#{input[0]} #{input[0]}"
    else
        input[1].times do
            sentence.push(input[0])
        end
        sentence = sentence.join(" ")
        return sentence
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah! Yes indeed, thank you very much, even just moving that `.join` method out of the `.times` loop did the trick as it should return the last line anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little more compact way of doing that:

```
def say_hey(word, repeat=1)
  puts ([word]*repeat).join(' ')
end

say_hey("Hey!")
  #=> Hey!
say_hey("Hey!", 14)
  #=> Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey! Hey!
```

Comment: So adding a value to the second argument creates a default if no second argument is provided?

Comment: That is correct. Note also the first form of the method [Array#*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2A).